# llenar select desde web-service (nusoap)

Tags: php, nusoap

Tengo muchas dudas sobre como plantear el siguiente problema:

tengo 2 tablas relacionadas mediante un id (productos y categorías) y necesito mostrar los productos de determinada categoría, el problema es que esta tabla (productos) la consumo desde un web service (Nusoap) que me devuelve un array asociativo con todos los productos , la idea es cargar desde un formulario un select para poder elegir la categoría y visualizar el/los producto/s resultante/s, pero no logro cargar las categorias en el select... alguna idea sobre como resolver esto?

```
              tabla Categoria (int identificador pk, varchar nombre);
              tabla Producto (int identificador pk, varchar nombre, int categoria fk);
```

Este es el formato del array consumido con 2 productos:

```
      Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [identificador] => 3 [nombre] => Pelota [categoria] => 5 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [identificador] => 4 [nombre] => Portatil [categoria] => 6 ) )
```

He intentado hacerlos de esta forma:

cliente.php

```
   <body>

      <h1>Tabla de productos</h1> 
         <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
              <p>Seleccione Categoria:</p>
               <select>
                 <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
                  <?php
                  require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
                  $client = new soapclient("http://localhost/Actividad5/servidor.php?wsdl");
                  $result = $client->listar();     //FUNCION WEB SERVICE
                  echo '<option value="'.$result['identificador'].'">'.$valores['nombre'].'</option>';    
                  ?>           
             </select>
           <button type="submit">VER</button>
```